# Why does strcat not work with empty string in C?

Tags: c, printf, strcat

Here is my program :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char arrcTest[256] = {0};
    strcat(arrcTest,"Hello");
    sprintf(arrcTest,"%s","World");
    strcat(arrcTest,"!!");
    printf("The String is=> %s\n",arrcTest);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with gcc version 4.8.3 and got the following output :-

```
The String is=> World!!
```

Why is strcat not working first time but it's working properly from second time onwards?

Comment: This is because `sprintf(arrcTest,"%s","World");` overwrite `arrcTest`.

Comment: you overwrote the `Hello` by `sprintf(arrcTest,"%s","World");`.

Comment: Recommend you dont use sprintf.  Use  snprintf , sprintf_s or equivalent that will prevent you from accidentally overrunning the buffer.

Comment: @skimon snprintf should be used in place of sprintf_s if available (the latter is not standard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sprintf` is not the same as `strcat`.  `sprintf` formats the string and puts it at the beginning of the buffer.  `strcat`, on the other hand, appends the string to the end of the buffer.

```
strcat(arrcTest,"Hello");   /* after this statement you have "Hello" in arrcTest */  
sprintf(arrcTest,"%s","World");  /* after this statement you have "World" in arrcTest */
strcat(arrcTest,"!!");    /* after this statement you have "World!!" in arrcTest */
```

Answer (score 3):

This statement is completely overwriting the first strcat:

```
sprintf(arrcTest,"%s","World");
```

Answer (score 1):

The first strcat is working. Only you overwrote it in the next statement

```
sprintf(arrcTest,"%s","World");
```

If you do not want that the first result of strcat would be overwritten then you can write

```
sprintf( arrcTest + strlen( arrcTest )," %s","World");
```

The other approaches are

```
int main(void)
{
    char arrcTest[256] = {0};
    strcat(arrcTest,"Hello");
    strcat(arrcTest, " World");
    strcat(arrcTest,"!!");
    printf("The String is=> %s\n",arrcTest);
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main(void)
{
    char arrcTest[256] = {0};
    sprintf(arrcTest,"%s %s%s", "Hello", "World", "!!" );
    printf("The String is=> %s\n",arrcTest);
    return 0;
}
```